# How can I directly test the methods of MyUserService for securesocial plugin for Play Framework

Tags: scala, playframework, specs2, securesocial

I'm wondering how I can test my implemented `UserService` (`MyUserService`) methods directly. I've imported `MyUserService` but it doesn't seem to recognize it.

The error is:

```
not found: value MyUserService
```

Thanks for any help you can give. Here's my test case for the find method.

Here's my test case...

```
"retrieve a user by UserId" in new WithApplication  {

  val user : Option[User]  = MyUserService.find(UserId("johnnyboy", "userpass"))

  val getUser = user.get

  getUser.uid must equalTo(Some(1))
  getUser.id.id must equalTo ("johnnyboy")
  getUser.id.providerId must equalTo("userpass")
  getUser.userType must equalTo(Some("admin"))
  getUser.firstName must equalTo("John")
  getUser.lastName must equalTo("Smith")
  getUser.fullName must equalTo("John Smith)
  getUser.email must equalTo(Some("johnsmith@gmail.com"))
  getUser.avatarUrl must equalTo(None)
  getUser.authMethod must equalTo(AuthenticationMethod("userPassword"))
  getUser.oAuth1Info must equalTo(None)
  getUser.oAuth2Info must equalTo(None)
  getUser.passwordInfo.get.hasher must equalTo(PasswordHasher.BCryptHasher)
  getUser.passwordInfo.get.password must      equalTo("$2a$10$eYPUTBSjprjKKmUf4m4XRuwurSxKKwbw13eP6WyDNk/LdpKgBytda")
  getUser.passwordInfo.get.salt must equalTo(None)
}
```

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should retrieve the `MyUserService` plugin instance from the play application and invoke the find method on the retrieved `MyUserService` instance.
How you're doing it (as shown above) `find` would have to be defined in a `MyUserService` object.

**Update:** The `MyUserService` plugin can be retrieved like this:

```
"retrieve a user by UserId" in new WithApplication  {
  val userService = implicitApp.plugin(classOf[MyUserService]).get
  ...
}
```

Comment: How do I retrieve the plugin instance? find is already defined in the object. Thanks!

Comment: Ok i tried it and got the following error... ould not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type org.specs2.execute.AsResult[plugins.MyUserService]
[error]     "retrieve a user by UserId" in new MyUserService(new FakeApplication()) {

Comment: I updated the answer with a code sample that shows how to retrieve the plugin instance. Btw, in scala an "object" creates a singleton object of a class, see e.g. http://twitter.github.io/scala_school/basics2.html#object. In this case, `find` is not defined on an object but on the class, and you can invoke it on an instance of the class.

Comment: I'd upvote but still new here. Thanks Martin it worked great.